# How to extract all the values from this Json for Assertion?

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

My json response I get as a string. I am trying to write a generic Assertion method to check if a property name is equal to the correct value. I am not able to extract all entire json.. In the Children token only comes comes the first set. How can I get the entire json for this validation.
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "NoTag",
    "type": 0,
    "query": null,
    "parentId": null,
    "ownerId": null,
    "activeDirectoryId": null,
    "hasChildren": false
  }

```
"[
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "NoTag",
    "type": 0,
    "query": null,
    "parentId": null,
    "ownerId": null,
    "activeDirectoryId": null,
    "hasChildren": false
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "NewTag",
    "type": 0,
    "query": null,
    "parentId": null,
    "ownerId": "eccf46f3-348b-422e-8789-c163b5953b41",
    "activeDirectoryId": null,
    "hasChildren": false
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "JohnTag",
    "type": 0,
    "query": null,
    "parentId": null,
    "ownerId": "eccf46f3-348b-422e-8789-c163b5953b41",
    "activeDirectoryId": null,
    "hasChildren": false
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "MyTag",
    "type": 0,
    "query": null,
    "parentId": null,
    "ownerId": "eccf46f3-348b-422e-8789-c163b5953b41",
    "activeDirectoryId": null,
    "hasChildren": false
  }
]"
```

//Here is the my Assertion method

```
public static void VerifyJsonString(IRestResponse response, string Property, string Value)
        {
            var res = response.Content; //using Restsharp 

            JArray jsonObject = JArray.Parse(response.Content);
            foreach (JObject content in jsonObject.Children<JObject>())
            {
                foreach (JProperty prop in content.Properties().Where(p => p.Name == Property))
                {
                    Assert.That(prop.Value, Is.EqualTo(Value));
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the property name for each element from the JSON array using the following code

```
        JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(response.Content);
        foreach (var element in jArray)
        {
            var propName = element["name"];
            Assert.That(prop.Value, Is.EqualTo(propName));
        }
```